# jquery - toFixed but not toFixed

Tags: javascript, integer, decimal

Using *toFixed* like follows gives:

```
var a=0.5, b=1, c=1.5;
console.log(a.toFixed(), b.toFixed(), c.toFixed());
// 0.5 1.0 1.5
```

However, when it's a whole number, I only want it to return "1".

Help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393332/javascript-tofixed-function

Comment: this question actually has nothing to do with jquery. toFixed is built into javascript.

Comment: I opened this page in hopes of Shakespeare.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a Regular Expression to remove a trailing `.0`, if it exists:

```
Number.prototype.safe_toFixed = function (x) {
    var that = this.toFixed(x);
    return that.replace(/\.0$/, '');
}
```

Comment: you know you're messing with the `Number` prototype? That could affect other scripts on the page!

Comment: @Cody I think that deserves a flag, disregarding who is getting insulted :)

Comment: @belisarius: See, that's exactly the question in my mind. Is it really "offensive" if you're only offending yourself? Then my head exploded because I was trying to make sense of it in the first place.

Comment: @Cody Ohh I see. You think of this as suicide deserving or not death penalty. I just see a flag. Perhaps my biorhythm is low on poetry today :)

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did and it works every time.

```
var x= Number(54.03).toFixed(1);

  if(Math.floor(x) == x) {
     x = Math.floor(x);
  }

alert( x );
```

I am just comparing the two types to see if they match. If they do, then I know there may or may not be an extra zero. Either way, I simply round up (ceil) or down (floor) and get the whole number with no annoying decimal and trailing zero.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `split()` and a `if` condition:

```
    var digit = 1.2
    var ret = digit.toFixed(1);
    var intValue = ret.split('.');
    if(intValue[1] == 0){
      digit = intValue[0];
    }
```